# On Seiberg-Witten theory in 3d and 4d

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, topological-field-theory, category-theory, seiberg-witten-theory

According to Gukov et al. in [this 2017 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06567.pdf) Seiberg-Witten theory in 4d *categorifies* Seiberg-Witten theory in 3d. In what sense is this phrase mentioned? I know what the process of categorification is (e.g. how Khovanov homology categorifies Jones polynomial).

What is the exact relation between the 3d and 4d versions of Seiberg-Witten theory and in what sense is the latter the categorification of the former?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06567

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I will do in the future.